# getting the id of the portlet that is moved in jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using jQuery UI [sortable portlets](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#portlets) to all the portlets I assign a data id. 
The HTML structure for one portlet element can be seen as follows:

```
 <div class="portlet" data-id= "6">
        <div class="portlet-header"><h6>Heading</h6></div>
        <div class="portlet-content">First Person</div>
        <div class="portlet-content">10</div>
      </div>
```

Now as similar to the demo as in the link above, I have three columns. To all the columns I have given an `id` of 1, 2, 3.

```
<div class="column" id="1">
```

the portlet structure resides inside these divs.

Now when a portlet is moved from one column to another, I can easily get the `id` of the column to which it has been placed as follows:

```
$( ".column" ).sortable({
    connectWith: ".column",
    handle: 'h6',
    receive: function(event, ui) {
      console.log(this);
    }
```

The only thing I want to get is, the `data-id` of the portlet that has been moved.

How can I get that?
The **jsFiddle** is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rUbQL/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The element that was moved is available in the `item` property of the `ui` argument passed to the `receive` handler, so you can write:

```
console.log(ui.item.data("id"));
```

You will find an updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rUbQL/1/).

Comment: thanks, i was new to jquery, learnt a lesson to console log other parameters as well (*ui*, *event*) apart from *this* will give better insights.